# Python - Count elements in list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find a simple way of getting a count of the number of elements in a list:

```
MyList = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I want to know there are 3 elements in this list.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems this is the first google result for `python list check number of elements`, instead of the linked question that this duplicates.

Answer (score 428):

[`len()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len)

```
>>> someList=[]
>>> print len(someList)
0
```

Comment: My IDE is showing a list.count (...) builtin, but it takes a mysterious argument, doesn't return the right answer, and its documentation is hard to find.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations

Answer (score 101):

just do [`len(MyList)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len)

This also works for `strings`, `tuples`, `dict` objects.

Answer (score 58):

`len(myList)` should do it.

`len` works with all the collections, and strings too.

Answer (score 43):

```
len()
```

it will count the element in the list, tuple and string and dictionary,
eg.

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3] #list
>>> len(mylist)
3
>>> word = 'hello' # string 
>>> len(word)
5
>>> vals = {'a':1,'b':2} #dictionary
>>> len(vals)
2
>>> tup = (4,5,6) # tuple 
>>> len(tup)
3
```

To learn Python you can use [byte of python](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=byte%20of%20python&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/files/120/byteofpython_120.pdf&ei=cWGSUJvYA4LsrAeSk4GACA&usg=AFQjCNHp7ZTqo0_e8WqSjtbsTez_aORjeQ) , it is best ebook for python beginners.

Answer (score 27):

To find count of unique elements of list use the combination of `len()` and `set()`.

```
>>> ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2]
>>> len(ls)
7
>>> len(set(ls))
4
```

Answer (score 13):

You can get element count of list by following two ways:

```
>>> l = ['a','b','c']
>>> len(l)
3
```

---

```
>>> l.__len__() 
3
```

Answer (score 11):

Len won't yield the total number of objects in a nested list (including multidimensional lists). If you have `numpy`, use `size()`.  Otherwise use list comprehensions within recursion.